# PHPSECLIB file upload with progress

Tags: php, phpseclib

```
$sftp->put($to, $from, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

How to display a real-time progress bar using phpseclib put?
I already did, while uploading sending ajax with interval to check the file size.

Does someone have better idea how to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phpseclib 1.0.x:

```
$sftp->put('filename.ext', str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024), NET_SFTP_STRING, -1, -1, function($sent) {
    echo "sent: $sent\n";
});
```

phpseclib 2.0.x:

```
$sftp->put('filename.ext', str_repeat('a', 1024 * 1024), SFTP::SOURCE_STRING, -1, -1, function($sent) {
    echo "sent: $sent\n";
});
```

Comment: @clickhere - it doesn't look like it. My suggestion: open an issue on github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib requesting the feature. Speaking from my own experience, I've found the author of that library to be fairly responsive.